# Make some properties within a Typescript interface optional

Tags: javascript, typescript

We have the Partial utility type to make all the fields of an interface optional.

for example:

```
interface A {
 a: string;
 b: string;
 c: string;
}
type A_Optional = Partial<A>
```

Now, I was looking for a built-in utility type which can help in making ***some*** fields optional.

For example, a and b become optional, while c stays required.

For example something like:

```
type X = Optionalize<A, 'a', 'b'>
```

```
// a?: optional
// b?: optional
// c: required
```

---

here's what I've reached so far

```
type Optionalize<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>;
```

It's not working

and I want to have unlimited number of fields which I can specify, ex:

```
Optionalize<A, 'x', 'y', 'z', ...etc>
```

Comment: `Optionalize<A, 'x' | 'y' | 'z' | ...etc>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a new type using the helpers `Omit`, `Partial` and `Pick`:

```
type X = Omit<A, 'a' | 'b'> & Partial<Pick<A, 'a' | 'b'>>;
```

Additionally, you can create your own generic utility type as such:

```
export type Optionalize<T, Union extends keyof T> = Omit<T, Union> & Partial<Pick<T, Union>>;
```

Now you can write:

```
import { Optionalize } from "./types.ts";
type X = Optionalize<A, "a" | "b">;
```

**When using type `X`, if the `c` key is missing, then, you'll get:**
[image]

**Here is a video showing usage:**
https://www.loom.com/share/18a6b6323bfd472caf3fd1d702e49d61

Comment: Can you wrap it into the Optionalize utility type I am trying to create?

Comment: Amazing, thanks!. 
and wow, what's the name of this vs code extension providing comments beside your writings?

Comment: GitLens is the extension that you are referring to.